# Delete ACLs created after a specific time in Documentum data storage

Tags: acl, dql, documentum, dfc

I've been doing some experiments on my data storage and for that reason I've created a handful of fake `ACLs` . Now I want to delete them . So I queried the data storage using the following :

```
select * from dm_Acl enable (row_based)
```

But then I realized that there is no such attribute as date created or modified or any thing else related to date what so ever . Then (with doubt) I thought that alcs might be considered as  DM_SYSOBJECT but then I queried a specific alc name that I had in mind but there was no result . I was wondering if there is any approach for me to meet my objective ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you must not delete ACL based on their creation date (moreover this is not possible), as there are might be objects referenced with an ACL.
So, I think what you really need is to delete orphaned ACL objects (which are not referenced with any objects).
There is a dm_DMClean Documentum Job which does exactly this.
However, I'm currently not sure if it deletes orphaned custom dm_acl objects or only automatically created ones which name starts with dm_45.. (I haven't been working with DCTM for a long time already), but it is easy to check - make sure you have an orphaned ACL, run the job and check if your acl was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Sergi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41258730/3472757) is pretty much good, but I had issue with deliberately deleted ACL's on production environment. Whole issue was fixed by simply creating new ACL's. It seems that there is no additional link between object's ACL property and ACL object itself, so in case of a problem it should be easily fixable.

Since you say this is your development environment you can go ahead and delete ACL's you don't want to have in your environment. In this situation it's wise to run ConsistencyChecker job from time to time.

Check for orphaned ACL's, if there is no orphaned objects then try to query objects you created during your development period and `JOIN` ACL properties from created objects to `dm_acl` table.